# Only show link text when a bootstrap navbar is collapsed

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

**How do I show link text beside a link's icon/badge *only* when a `navbar` is collapsed?**

Right now my `bootstrap3` driven `navbar` uses only icons, when it is uncollapsed:

[image]

This is problematic when the `navbar` is collapsed:

[image]

... there is no descriptive text beside the links, but there is clearly room for it. The removal of text descriptions is for saving space, but once collapsed there is ample space... and it seems to be defective without descriptions, since so much real-estate is taken up.

I've looked through helper classes, and `collapse` functionality in the documentation, and tried to put `<span class='collapse in'>` tags in containing text, after the `badge` or `glyphicon` tags.

When I do that, the text is always visible, not only when the `navbar` is collapsed. I would prefer not to use `class='visible-xs'` or another class like it, based on actual browser width.

What is the correct way to detect an element is in a collapsed `navbar` and only show text in that case?

**Here's a gist:** https://gist.github.com/digitalextremist/6e70807a8b0e3c3da993

And bootply: http://www.bootply.com/105538

Comment: Can you create a [Bootply](http://bootply.com) or fiddle with your code?

Comment: And added a gist. Also used bootply. I see you're the creator of that. Never used it. Seems very useful.

Comment: Is there any reason you don't use jQuery? Just curious. http://stackoverflow.com/a/18568776/2930161

Comment: What event would I be listening for to use jQuery to modify my interface?

Answer (score 7):

I have tried to do something similar with the `.in` class added by Bootstrap's Collapse plugin for jQuery, but it was not very reliable as the class would stay after the navbar would collapse and then uncollapse.

I recommend using CSS media queries instead. In Bootstrap 3's `navbar.less` file, `786px` is used as the breakpoint for collapsing the navbar, so I would recommend using that in your CSS.

```
/* standard navbar */
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  ...
}

/* mobile navbar */
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. This solved the delay issue I asked about in the other answer. Best answer.

Comment: Maybe a bit late but useful for people who stumble across this question:
It's best to use the bootstrap variables `@grid-float-breakpoint` and `@grid-float-breakpoint-max` instead of the concrete pixel values, so if you want to change you breakpoint your code doesn't break.

Comment: You're right, but you can only use them if you build Bootstrap yourself (which is recommended if you're using Less or Sass).

Answer (score 4):

Maybe I did not understand the question right, but isnt it as simple as use the hidden class?

```
<li class="hidden-xs"><a href="#">Action</a></li>
```

Comment: This is a perfect option! However, I think he's looking for `.visible-xs-inline`, to add a line of text to the existing dropdown, not add a new one. New answer coming.

Answer (score 4):

Going off @pungggi's answer:

Since bootstrap already has the media query breaks defined, there are helper responsive classes to show/hide things based on the same breaks that the grids use: `hidden-(size)` and `visible-(size)`. This way, if you ever make your own less/sass based template, you don't have to change the @media-query parameters in multiple places. (see http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes for more info)

So adding a `span` or `p` tag with the `.visible-xs-inline` class will ensure that the specified text is only shown when the screen is determined 'xs', which is used as the breaking point for collapsing the nav menu, and the `-inline` part will make sure it displays inline, since the `.visible-xs` will use `display:block` by default.

Code snippet:

```
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">
                <span class="fa fa-plus"></span>
                <!-- The following span will only show 
                     when the nav menu is collapsed -->
                <span class="visible-xs-inline">ADD SOMETHING BUTTON</span>
            </a>
             <!-- all the dropdown stuff -->
         </li>

         <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">
                <span class="fa fa-compass" title="Energy Compass"></span>
                <span class="visible-xs-inline">ENERGY COMPASS</span>
            </a>
             <!-- all the dropdown stuff -->
         </li>
         <!-- continued list -->
    </ul>
```

Note: I recommend using a css padding/margin, or `&nbsp;`'s to ensure that the span text is properly padded but won't breakline.

Comment: I just added this to my own app, and it was way easier/cleaner than adding in extra css with media-queries just to hide some text in the nav

Comment: Also, apparently the non-display-specifying classes, (`.visible-sm` vs `.visible-sm-block`) are depreciated, and will be removed in Bootstrap v4. The more you know!

Answer (score 3):

What about

```
.navbar-collapse .text-you-want-hidden-on-desktop {
  display: none;
}

.navbar-collapse.in .text-you-want-hidden-on-desktop {
  display: inline;
}
```

I believe the comment above about jQuery was implying that you could watch for the `show.bs.collapse` event, and act accordingly. More info about that event:
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse

But I believe you can accomplish what you want with CSS.

Comment: So far this works, but there is a slight delay when the collapsible version of the navbar is opened. Do you have a remedy for that piece?

Comment: Another issue I have seen with this approach, is that the `.in` class will stay if the window is resized to small, the menu opened, then resized back past the threshold again - making this approach non-ideal

Comment: The delay is caused by the css class `.collapsing` replacing `.collapse` and `.collapse.in`, while the menu is moving/animating. You could fix the delay by adding in `.navbar-collapse.collapsing .text-you-want-hidden-on-desktop {display: inline;}` as well, to ensure that it is shown while the menu is moving, but you still run into the state problem that I explained above, where you could end up with them shown while the screen is un-collapsed/ larger than the mobile break.